# How can I use the Mac file selection menu in my own program?

Tags: macos, path

In almost any desktop application that I've used, it's possible to select a path to open or save files using what appears to be a standard file navigator that looks just like Finder. For example, if I go to save this webpage, 
[this menu comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmB6O.png), and I can select where to save it, create a new folder, etc. Is there a system call to start this menu from my own program, and presumably return a path to the selected file or folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`NSOpenPanel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/index.html).

It does exactly what you seem to be looking for:

> The NSOpenPanel class provides the Open panel for the Cocoa user interface. Applications use the Open panel as a convenient way to query the user for the name of a file to open.

Comment: That looks very promising. Would it be possible to make a system call to that from Python, for example?

Comment: Never mind, got it! I posted the code below. [Here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@v@i@virtaal-HEAD@virtaal@support@native_widgets.py/233/AppKit.NSOpenPanel) is an example of its use.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else sees this, Johannes Weiß's answer is correct: NSOpenPanel is exactly what I was looking for. In Python, the code for it looks like this:

```
from AppKit import NSOpenPanel
# the following import is only used to prevent multiselect and directory select
from objc import NO
panel = NSOpenPanel.openPanel()

# set the title (not required)
panel.setTitle("open file")

# prevent multiselect and directory select (not required)
panel.setAllowsMultipleSelection_(NO)
panel.setCanChooseDirectories_(NO)

# open the panel
panel.runModal()

# get the path
path = panel.filenames()[0]
```

A longer example can be found [here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@v@i@virtaal-HEAD@virtaal@support@native_widgets.py/233/AppKit.NSOpenPanel).